# How to speed up C++ MySQL connector?

Tags: c++, mysql, performance, optimization

I am using C++ MySQL connector.

```
sql::Connection * db = nullptr;

try {
    db = get_driver_instance()->connect("tcp://localhost:3306", "admin", "admin");
    db->setSchema("test_db");
} 
catch(exception &e) {
    return 1;  
}
```

The MySQL connector is dynamically linked to the application.

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64
LDLIBS = -lmysqlcppconn
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11 -O3
```

When I run my application it takes about `13 033 µs` and about `10 000 µs` is only this connection to MySQL. I also tried to compile it using static library, but it didn't help.

**Is there any way to speed up the database connection?**

Comment: Are you establishing new connection for each operation? If so, you may consider pooling them.

Comment: No, the connection is created only once when the application starts...

Comment: please show a [mre]. we can't tell you how to optimise the code that we can't see

Comment: The time it takes to make a connection will depend on the MySQL server (and the speed of the connection). This is not about your application ebing quicker it is about the server you are connecting to being quicker. Where is the MySQL server, What authentication method are you using to connect.

Comment: Actually I am using MAMP (on MacBook Pro 2017) for testing. I added example of connection.

Comment: 10 000 µs is 0.01 second. What application are you creating that you need reduce this time?

Comment: I am getting a lot of requests via HTTPs and web server spawns new instance of app for each connection. Actually I tried to connect to the database in PHP script and it takes almost the same time.

Comment: `web server spawns new instance of app for each connection` yeah, this is where you lose out on connection pooling as every instance of the app will create its own db connection.

Comment: Yes, but how to say to server: give me pointer to DB connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to say to server: give me pointer to DB connection

MySQL connections cannot be shared between processes. If your C++ process starts when an http request is handled, it must open a new MySQL connection at that time.

More typically, a high-performance web app does not fork a new process for every http request. You're designing code using the 1990's-era CGI protocol and expecting high performance, you should change your architecture.

For example, a [FastCGI](http://cgi.sourceforge.net) implementation should handle many http requests with a single process. That way you can use a connection pool that provides MySQL connections to request handlers without needing to reopen the connection every time.

To speed up individual MySQL connections, consider:

- Upgrade at least to MySQL 5.7, to take advantage of improved connection speed. I thought I read that 8.0 improved this speed even further, but I can't find a reference for that right now.
- Use the UNIX domain socket interface, which is faster than TCP/IP connections. It should be as simple as using "localhost" when connecting the client to the MySQL server.
- If you do use TCP/IP, then set the option `skip_name_resolve`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/host-cache.html says:

> If you have a very slow DNS and many hosts, you might be able to improve performance either by enabling `skip_name_resolve` to disable DNS lookups, or by increasing the value of `host_cache_size` to make the host cache larger.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you add one more links how to use FastCGI?

Comment: http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/

Comment: Really, FastCGI is a mature technology with abundant resources. You may just Google for "fastcgi C++" or  similar search terms.